# How to use for loop in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I've created few map areas in an image. I want to display the description of particular area onclick. I used one javascript function. Image contains around 15-20 map areas. Below is simple function for only 3 areas. This one working fine.

```
function showdiv(id) {
                obj = document.getElementById(id);
                alert(obj);

                if (obj.style.display == 'block') {
                    obj.style.display = 'none';
                }
                if (obj.style.display == 'none') {
                    if (obj == whatever1) {
                        whatever1.style.display = 'block';
                        whatever2.style.display = 'none';
                        whatever3.style.display = 'none';
                    } else if (obj == whatever2) {
                        whatever2.style.display = 'block';
                        whatever1.style.display = 'none';
                        whatever3.style.display = 'none';
                    } else if (obj == whatever3) {
                        whatever3.style.display = 'block';
                        whatever2.style.display = 'none';
                        whatever1.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }
```

I believe this is method not fair for more than 15 map areas. So i tried to use for loop. But something went wrong.

```
 <script>
                function showdiv(id) {
                    obj = document.getElementById(id);
                    if (obj.style.display == 'block') {
                        obj.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    if (obj.style.display == 'none') {
                        for (var i=0; i<=12; i++) {
                            var div = whatever + i;
                            if (div == obj) {
                                div.style.display = 'block';
                                home.style.display = 'none';
                            } else {
                                div.style.display = 'none';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
</script>
```

What's the solution to this basic problem? Anybody have any suggestion?? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `var div = whatever + i;` - I assume in the variable `div` you are expecting a DOM element? That's not going to happen with that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you summarize all your `wahtever` elements with classes. i.e:

```
<div id="whatever1" class="whateverElement"/>
```

Then in your function you can handle them all the same:

```
function showdiv(id) {
        obj = document.getElementById(id);
        var isBlock = (obj.style.display == 'block');

        //first change all elments
        var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName("whateverElement");

        for(var e in allElements){
            var element = allElements[e];
            element.style.display = "none";
        }

        //now change the value for the object with the given id
        if (isBlock) {
            obj.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            obj.style.display = 'block';
        }
}
```

Just to show that it can be worth having a look at "jQuery" for such tasks the following code would do the same as above using jQuery:

```
function showdiv(id) {
    $(".whateverElement").hide();
    $("#" + id).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `whatever` is a `string` then you can do as following:

```
var whatever = whatever+i;
var div = $(whatever);
alert(div);
if (div == obj) {
//.....your code continue.......
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get your elements by

```
div = document.getElementById("whatever" + i);
```

then manage it as you did...